# add text on polarplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I am trying to plot angles and add the angles as text. This is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2) # changes the 0 to be at the top
ax.set_theta_direction(-1) # clockwise 
# ax.set_facecolor(green_plot_temp) # sets the background color

angle0 = 260
angle1 = 280

actual = np.radians(np.arange(angle0,angle1,1))
expected = np.arange(angle0,angle1,1)
r, theta = np.meshgrid(expected, actual)
values = np.ones((actual.size, expected.size))

# plot slice 
ax.contourf(theta, r, values, colors='r') # color of the slice
      
# add the angles as text
text0_x = str(angle0)
text1_x = str(angle1)
ax.text(np.radians(angle0), ax.get_rmax(), text0_x, color="blue", ha='right', va='bottom', fontdict={'fontsize':11})
ax.text(np.radians(angle1), ax.get_rmax(), text1_x, color="blue", ha='left', va='top', fontdict={'fontsize':11})
```

This gives: [image: output figure]

Now, I don't understand why the text 260 is outside the figure (that's the result I want obv.), and the text 280 is inside.

Replacing the angles with

```
angle0 = 160
angle1 = 270
```

Gives this figure:
[image: output figure]

I am quite lost.

In the end I am looping all that and making a lot of figures with different angles, and so far I have not managed to obtain consistent results with different angles.

Comment: ok I got something that works: ax.get_rmax()+0.15*(ax.get_rmax()-ax.get_rmin()) instead of ax.get_rmax(). any more elegant solution?

Comment: Why are the `horizontalalignment` settings different? Shouldn't it just be aligned to the right?